# Prove: If $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\gcd(2a,2b)=2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What I came up with is:

Let $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $1|a$ and $1|b$.
There exists a, $d$ and $c$ such that $d(1)=a$ and $c(1)=b$.
Then, $(2)d=(2)a$ and $(2)c=(2)b$.
Thus, $2|2a$ and $2|2b$.
So, $(2a,2b)=2$.

Is this not specific enough? How would I prove $2$ is the "greatest" common divisor?

Comment: `$\gcd(a,b)=1$` shows $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This might be a useful characterisation of $n=\gcd(a,b)$: it is the smallest positive integer that can be written on the form $$n=xa+yb$$for integers $x,y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep on going: suppose $\gcd(2a,2b)=x> 2$. Since $2$ is a common divisor we have $2\mid x$, i.e. $x=2y$ where $y\neq1$. This leads to $2a=xs=2ys$ and $2b=xt=2yt$ for some $s,t$. Thus $a=ys$ and $b=yt$, since $\gcd(a,b)=1$ we must have $y=1$, a contradiction. So $\gcd(2a,2b)$ must be $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S=\{ma+nb:m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$

By Euclid's Theorem $gcd(a,b)$ is the smallest positive integer in $S$. Thus there exists an $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $xa+yb=1$.

Obviously then  $x(2a)+y(2b)=2$ so $2 \in S^*=\{m(2a)+n(2b):m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Assume by way of contradiction that $1 \in S^*$. There then exists two integers $x^*,y^* \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $x^*(2a)+y^*(2b)=1$ and so $x^*(a)+y^*(b)=1/2$. An obvious contradiction as the sum of two integers cannot lead to a non-integer rational.

We have shown then that $2$ is the smallest positive integer in $S^*$ and so by Euclid's Theorem $gcd(2a,2b)=2$